# Unable to create a Materialized view on the below query

Tags: oracle12c

Hope you all well.
I am able execute the below code and got the right output in oracle.But when trying to create a view its giving the error - a column may not be joined to sub query.
The view is getting created in sql server on the same query but in oracle its giving an error.please help.

```
select c.Contractid
FROM    FCT_EIT_CONTRACT c LEFT OUTER JOIN
DIM_EIT_PROCESS_INSTANCE psi   ON psi.SURR_ID = c.PROCESS_INSTANCE_SKEY 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN                 
    DIM_EIT_ACTION wa               ON psi.ACTION_SKEY wa.SURR_ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN         
    DIM_EIT_ACTION_HISTORY  ah      ON wa.SURR_ID = ah.ACTION_SKEY 

    AND psi.SURR_ID = ah.PROCESS_INSTANCE_SKEY 
    AND ah.ACTION_HISTORY_ID =(SELECT  MAX(ACTION_HISTORY_ID) AS Expr1
   FROM  DIM_EIT_ACTION_HISTORY  a
   WHERE (PROCESS_INSTANCE_SKEY = c.PROCESS_INSTANCE_SKEY) 
   AND 
  (psi.ACTION_SKEY = ACTION_SKEY)))  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
 DIM_EIT_STEP ws ON ws.SURR_ID = wa.NEXT_STEP_SKEY
 WHERE (psi.CurrentStepId NOT IN (100, 130, 131, 132, 900, 902, 910))
```

Comment: I am not familiar with that error, but the subquery obviously has something to do with it.  Maybe you could try rewriting your query so that it avoids using a subquery.

Comment: Thank You @ Tim .I have rewritten the query  in oracle but out of 1000 there are 17 contract ids which are missing.But the case is different in sql server.I am getting exact output in sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
```

c.contractid 
FROM    FCT_EIT_CONTRACT c , DIM_EIT_PROCESS_INSTANCE psi, DIM_EIT_ACTION wa, DIM_EIT_ACTION_HISTORY  ah, 
                      (select MAX(ACTION_HISTORY_ID) AS ACTION_HISTORY_ID, ACTION_SKEY, PROCESS_INSTANCE_SKEY from DIM_EIT_ACTION_HISTORY group by ACTION_SKEY, PROCESS_INSTANCE_SKEY) a , 
              DIM_EIT_STEP ws
                     where psi.SURR_ID(+) = c.PROCESS_INSTANCE_SKEY
                     and  psi.ACTION_SKEY = wa.SURR_ID(+)
                     and wa.SURR_ID = ah.ACTION_SKEY(+)
                    AND psi.SURR_ID = ah.PROCESS_INSTANCE_SKEY(+)
                    AND ah.ACTION_HISTORY_ID = a.ACTION_HISTORY_ID(+)
          and ((a.ACTION_HISTORY_ID is not null and ah.ACTION_HISTORY_ID is not null and ah.PROCESS_INSTANCE_SKEY is not null) or 
                (a.ACTION_HISTORY_ID is null and ah.ACTION_HISTORY_ID is null and ah.PROCESS_INSTANCE_SKEY is null))
--          and 
--                  and c.PROCESS_INSTANCE_SKEY = a.PROCESS_INSTANCE_SKEY(+)
--          and psi.ACTION_SKEY = a.ACTION_SKEY
                    and ws.SURR_ID`+) = wa.NEXT_STEP_SKEY
           and       (psi.CurrentStepId NOT IN (100, 130, 131, 132, 900, 902, 910)) and contractid in (1313,27, 221)

Answer (score 0):

Would it help if you moved the offending part of the query to the `WHERE` clause, e.g.

```
SELECT c.contractid
FROM fct_eit_contract c
LEFT OUTER JOIN dim_eit_process_instance psi ON psi.surr_id = c.process_instance_skey
LEFT OUTER JOIN dim_eit_action wa            ON psi.action_skey wa.surr_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dim_eit_action_history ah    ON wa.surr_id = ah.action_skey
                                            AND psi.surr_id = ah.process_instance_skey
LEFT OUTER JOIN dim_eit_step ws              ON ws.surr_id = wa.next_step_skey
WHERE psi.currentstepid NOT IN (100, 130, 131, 132, 900, 902, 910)
  -- subquery moved down here
  AND  ah.action_history_id = (SELECT MAX(action_history_id) AS expr1
                               FROM dim_eit_action_history a
                               WHERE process_instance_skey = c.process_instance_skey
                                 AND psi.action_skey = action_skey
                              );
```

Comment: I have tried the above code but again there are missing contracts.